# How to calculate week number for each quarter for any given year in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
def first_day_quarter_f(our_date):

    quarter = our_date.quarter
    quarter_start_date= datetime(our_date.year, 3* quarter -2, 1)

    return quarter_start_date


def days_in_between_f(our_date):

    quarter_start_date=first_day_quarter_f(our_date)

    delta=our_date-quarter_start_date
    days=delta.days+1

    return days


def first_day_name_f(our_date):

    quarter_start_date=first_day_quarter_f(our_date)
    first_day=quarter_start_date.strftime("%A")

    return first_day


def week_f(our_date):

    days=days_in_between_f(our_date)
    first_day=first_day_name_f(our_date)

    if first_day=='Monday':
        if days<7:
            week=1
        else:
            if days%7==0:
                week=math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=math.floor(days/7)+1

    elif first_day=='Tuesday': 
        if days<6:
            week=1
        else:
            days=days-6
            if days%7==0:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)+1

    elif first_day=='Wednesday':
        if days<5:
            week=1
        else:
            days=days-5
            if days%7==0:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)+1

    elif first_day=='Thursday':
        if days<4:
            week=1
        else:
            days=days-4
            if days%7==0:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)+1

    elif first_day=='Friday':
        if days<3:
            week=1
        else:
            days=days-3
            if days%7==0:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)+1

    elif first_day=='Saturday':
        if days<3:
            week=1
        else:
            days=days-2
            if days%7==0:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)+1

    else:
        if days<3:
            week=1
        else:
            days=days-1
            if days%7==0:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)
            else:
                week=1+math.floor(days/7)+1

    return week
```

I have tried to get first day of quarter and then calculated difference between the date given and first day of quarter and then calculated the weekno on the basis of name of first day of quarter. Is there any other way to do this? We need 20-Aug-2020 is in which week of that quarter? Answer should be weekno-8.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
import math

date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"

a = datetime.strptime('1/1/2020', date_format)   # First day in the year, 1st January 2020

b = datetime.strptime('8/20/2020', date_format)  # Your date 20th August 2020

delta = b – a

num_days = delta.days

num_of_week = num_days / 7

week_in_quarter = num_of_week % 13

print(math.ceil(week_in_quarter))
```

Output:

8